# How to convert boost::string_view to std::string_view?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, string-view

I'm using a boost library which uses `boost::string_view`. However, I would like to use `std::string_view` in my code.
**Q:** What's the best way to convert between these two?

At the moment I'm using:

```
void foo(std::string_view sv) {
# ...
}
void foo(boost::string_view bsv) {
  foo(std::string(bsv));
}
```

But this creates an unnecessary string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way:

```
void foo(std::string_view sv);

inline void foo(boost::string_view bsv) {
  foo(std::string_view(bsv.data(), bsv.size()));
}
```

Make sure to pass the length into `std::string_view` otherwise it calls `Traits::length` (`std::strlen`) unnecessarily.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can switch beast using it's own string_view to std::string_view, by providing definition of `BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW`

Comment: Since boost-1.83.0 `BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW` is no longer available:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/release_notes.html